# Attribute error while creating CNN model in Keras

Tags: keras, conv-neural-network, attributeerror

The function used to build the model:

```
def CancerModel(input_shape):   

    X_input = Input(input_shape)

    X = ZeroPadding2D((2, 2))(X_input)

    X = Conv2D(8, (5, 5), strides = (1, 1), name = 'conv')(X)
    X = BatchNormalization(axis = 3, name = 'bn1')(X)
    X = Activation('relu')(X)

    X = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), name='max_pool')(X)

    X = Conv2D(16, (5, 5), strides = (1, 1), name = 'conv2')(X)
    X = BatchNormalization(axis = 3, name = 'bn2')(X)
    X = Activation('relu')(X)

    X = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), name='max_pool2')(X)

    X = Flatten()(X)
    X = Dense(120, activation='relu', name='fc1')(X)
    X = Dense(84, activation='relu', name='fc2')(X)
    X = Dense(7, activation='softmax', name='output')(X)

    model = Model(inputs = X_input, outputs = output, name='CancerModel')

    return model
```

The model was attempted to be created using:

```
cancerModel = CancerModel(X_train.shape[1:])
```

However, I am getting an error saying that the attribute can't be set.
I have also attached a screenshot of the error I'm getting. Any help would be appreciated.

[Screenshot of bug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6VjoF.png)

Comment: Can you share the code of your model? And please no screenshots, write the code here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found no error in your code. It may be problem in your `training data shape` or Keras version issue (My Keras version `2.4.3`).

```
def CancerModel(input_shape):   

    X_input = Input(input_shape)

    X = ZeroPadding2D((2, 2))(X_input)

    X = Conv2D(8, (5, 5), strides = (1, 1), name = 'conv')(X)
    X = BatchNormalization(axis = 3, name = 'bn1')(X)
    X = Activation('relu')(X)

    X = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), name='max_pool')(X)

    X = Conv2D(16, (5, 5), strides = (1, 1), name = 'conv2')(X)
    X = BatchNormalization(axis = 3, name = 'bn2')(X)
    X = Activation('relu')(X)

    X = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), name='max_pool2')(X)

    X = Flatten()(X)
    X = Dense(120, activation='relu', name='fc1')(X)
    X = Dense(84, activation='relu', name='fc2')(X)
    X = Dense(7, activation='softmax', name='output')(X)

    model = Model(inputs = X_input, outputs = X, name='CancerModel')

    return model


CancerModel((224,224,3)).summary() #It works fine
```

Also works fine using

```
CancerModel(np.ones((5,120,120,3)).shape[1:]).summary()
```

Comment: It worked fine after reinstalling Tensorflow and Keras. thanks.